# Getting width and height of image from UIImageView after aspect fit

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get the width and height of an image from UIImageView after it gets scaled to aspect fit. This is how I got its width and height:

```
let imageHeight = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: (transferImage.size), insideRect: imageView.frame).height
let imageWidth = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: (transferImage.size), insideRect: imageView.frame).width

let imageYposition = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: (transferImage.size), insideRect: imageView.frame).origin.y
let imageXposition = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: (transferImage.size), insideRect: imageView.frame).origin.x
```

Apparently, this gives me the width and height. However, after trying to size an UIView to the same dimensions, they are not the same size. This is how I set the UIView to the width and height of the image:

```
boundariesRectangle.frame = CGRect(x: imageXposition, y: imageYposition, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight)
```

This is what happens:

[image: This is what happens]

Comment: You can set it manually in your storyboard. It's easier that way

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
guard let image = imageView.image else { return }

// Calculate the scaled size of the image
let scaledRect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: image.size, insideRect: imageView.bounds)

// Create the overlay view
let overlayView = UIView(frame: .zero)
overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
overlayView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// Add the overlay
// To use relate 2 views by auto-layout constraints, they must have the
// same parent view
imageView.superView!.addSubview(overlayView)
overlayView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: scaledRect.width).isActive = true
overlayView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: scaledRect.height).isActive = true
overlayView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
overlayView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```